# Centered div with greater height than parent div on bootstrap and flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox, center

I'm trying to achive this...

[image: my two divs]

On the right side of the teal div should be text.

I can do this with position absolute, but i cant find any solution to do this with bootstrap and flexbox. With bootstrap and the way "row" and "col" the grey divs height is always equal to the teals div height, but i wont that.

Any ideas, how i can do it?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Can you share you html/css?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `absolute`, or `relative`, or in general other than `static` positioning, there is a way how to place one element above another using negative margins.

```css
.background {
  background-color: #AAA;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.foreground {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
<div class="foreground">
</div>
```